# Jupyter Notebook creates a .txt file - and doesn't let me save as .ipynb. Manually creating a .ipynb file doens't open a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to move my data science Environment to VSCODE, it seems a really powerfull IDE to deal with multiple languages and with great versatility,

But currently I'm dealing with an annoying issue with the python and jupyter extension,

**Expected behaviour**
Using command palette 'Jupyter: Create blank new Jupyter notebook' it should open a .ipynb file with all the features of a jupyter notebook.

(source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)

**Actual behaviour**
Using command palette 'Jupyter: Create new blank notebook' it opens a jupyter notebook with all the features and the proper jupyter notebook layout, but with extension .txt.

I tried to save it as .ipynb but returns and error and don't let me save it.

When I create a file manually with 'filename.ipynb' it creates a file with the jupyter icon, but without all the features of a jupyter notebook.. it is a simple plain script file like a .py file.

I already have done a lot of web search looking for some solution, but without success.

already tried reinstall vscode and downgrade some versions of the python and jupyter extensions, but all without success.

Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

**Environment data**
VS Code version: 1.59.0
Extension version : Python v2021.8.1105858891, Jupyter v2021.8.1195043623
OS and version: Windows 10 64bit
Python version : Python 3.9.6 64bit